# Problems transfering codeigniter 3.0 from localhost to live server hostgator

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I get a 404 page when trying to transfer codeigniter 3.0 from localhost to live server at hostgator. This is the data on my config file, the .htaccess and the index.php.

structure:

- application
- system
- index.php
- .htaccess

My config file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mysyite/';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

$config['url_suffix'] = '';

$config['language'] = 'english';

$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';

$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;

$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';

$config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;

$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';

$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger']   = 'c';
$config['function_trigger']     = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger']    = 'd'; // experimental not currently in use

$config['log_threshold'] = 4;

$config['log_path'] = '';

$config['cache_path'] = '';

$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

index.php

```
$system_path = 'system';

$application_folder = 'application';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all your controllers and models file names all start with capital letters.

> Starting with CodeIgniter 3.0, all class filenames (libraries,
>   drivers, controllers and models) must be named in a **Ucfirst-like**
>   manner or in other words - they **must start with a capital letter**.

Source: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html#step-2-update-your-classes-file-names

Comment: the files or the classes, I never got that... or both?

Comment: yeah its an annoying minimal issue of making those capitals.. Im glad you got it working